# Where is my custom Django app code?

Tags: python, django, pip

I built and installed my custom Django app following the official tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/reusable-apps/

The installation seems successful.

```
$ pip install --user ../horizon2fa-0.1.tar.gz

Processing /opt/stack/horizon2fa-0.1.tar.gz
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): horizon2fa==0.1 from file:///opt/stack/horizon2fa-0.1.tar.gz in /opt/stack/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Building wheels for collected packages: horizon2fa
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for horizon2fa ... done
  Stored in directory: /opt/stack/.cache/pip/wheels/a6/4a/f0/4533f85d90b8f1a274a35d3865a2e0b15ff85f0570a0708679
Successfully built horizon2fa
```

Where can I find the source code of all my custom classes and methods?

I tried to search it through my system but didn't find them. Is the code compiled?

```
$ sudo find / -name "*horizon2fa*"

/root/.cache/pip/wheels/a0/9d/24/d8070ea2a01759ce7ebc03c34393db8a5aceccd380e60481c5/horizon2fa-0.1-cp27-none-any.whl
/opt/stack/.cache/pip/wheels/a6/4a/f0/4533f85d90b8f1a274a35d3865a2e0b15ff85f0570a0708679/horizon2fa-0.1-cp27-none-any.whl
/opt/stack/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon2fa-0.1.dist-info
/opt/stack/horizon2fa-0.1.tar.gz
```

The module seems was not installed correctly.

```
python -c "import horizon2fa; print(horizon2fa.__path__)"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named horizon2fa
```

Below, you can see my app directory structure.

```
trex@trex:~/Development/openstack2FA/horizon2fa$ tree
.
├── admin.py
├── dist
│   └── horizon2fa-0.1.tar.gz
├── enabled
│   └── _31000_myplugin.py
├── horizon2fa.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── main.py
├── MANIFEST.in
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── panel.py
├── README.rst
├── setup.py
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   └── horizon2fa
│       ├── created.html
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── login.html
│       ├── new.html
│       └── view.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
├── user.py
└── views.py
```

And my setup.py script.

```
import os
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')) as readme:
    README = readme.read()

# allow setup.py to be run from any path
os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))

setup(
    name='horizon2fa',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    license='BSD License',  # example license
    description='A Django app.',
    long_description=README,
    url='http://www.trex.com/',
    author='trex',
    author_email='trex@trex.com',
    classifiers=[
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Framework :: Django :: X.Y',  # replace "X.Y" as appropriate
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',  # example license
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        # Replace these appropriately if you are stuck on Python 2.
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
    ],
)
```

Comment: Aren't they in `/opt/stack/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`?

Comment: Obviously you use Linux (or some other UNIX-style OS), so the install path is probably `/usr/local/lib/{{ your python version }}/site-packages`. This is at least the location under Debian based systems.

Comment: I don't see my source code in site-packages. ls -lh  /opt/stack/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon2fa-0.1.dist-info/
total 28K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stack stack  15 Feb 25 09:38 DESCRIPTION.rst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stack stack   4 Feb 25 09:38 INSTALLER
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stack stack 905 Feb 25 09:38 METADATA
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stack stack 967 Feb 25 09:38 metadata.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stack stack 735 Feb 25 09:38 RECORD
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stack stack  11 Feb 25 09:38 top_level.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stack stack  93 Feb 25 09:38 WHEEL

Comment: I have Fedora 23. $ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)

Comment: Look into `/opt/stack/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, not the `horizon2fa-0.1.dist-info` subdirectory. The `.dist-info` dir only contains pip metadata; the actual package would be inside `site-packages`.

Comment: $ ls -lh /opt/stack/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 stack stack 131 Feb 25 10:04 horizon2fa-0.1.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x 2 stack stack  45 Feb 25 09:38 migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used `--user`, the package is installed for current user (the one who issued `pip install --user`) and not in system `site-packages` directory. See the docs for [site.USER_BASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE). 
So, you should look in `~/.local/` as said in the docs, probably: `/home/%user%/.local/lib/python%version%/site-packages/`.

Also, considering, that the package got installed somewhere on PYTHONPATH, you could try to find it by running the following command in your shell:

```
python -c "import %module%; print(%module%.__path__)"
```

i.e.

```
python -c "import horizon2fa; print(horizon2fa.__path__)"
```

*Regarding your question update:*

You should create a top level directory, e.g. `django-horizon2fa` and put `setup.py`, `MANIFEST.in`, `README.RST`, `LICENSE.txt` and your `horizon2fa` package directory inside it. So that installation related files are in new dir and all files related to your module are inside a dir in that dir. Current directory setup doesn't allow [find_packages()](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) do it's job properly.

```
django-horizon2fa
│
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
├── setup.py
└── horizon2fa
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── user.py
    ├── views.py
    ├── enabled
    │   └── _31000_myplugin.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── panel.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── user.py
    ├──  views.py
    └── templates
        ├── base.html
        └── horizon2fa
            ├── created.html
            ├── index.html
            ├── login.html
            ├── new.html
            └── view.html
```

P.S. Using solely `MANIFEST.in`, may sometimes lead to problems with inclusion of package data in distribution, e.g. templates. In that case consider providing  files from `MANIFEST.in` in `package_data` dictionary to `setup()`, see [details in the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files).

Comment: I see only the dist info folder inside. $ ls -lh ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 stack stack 131 Feb 25 10:04 horizon2fa-0.1.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x 2 stack stack  45 Feb 25 09:38 migrations

Comment: @trex, please see answer update. If the import will fail, then probably the package has installation problem. Then you'll need to add your original package directory structure and `setup.py` to your question for further research. The're might be problems, if e.g. you used python2 pip to install the package and try to import it in a script ran via python3 - obviously the package get installed in different places for python2 pip and python3 pip.

Comment: Nikita, you are right, there is an installation problem. I have updated my question.

Comment: @trex, updated my answer. Please, try my advice and if the problem persists let us know.

Comment: Nikita, do you mean creating django-horizon2fa folder manually? I created the folder manually and copied there all files from openstack2FA Django project. Still doesn't work. Or maybe you mean start a new Django project with a different name? Like django-admin startproject django-horizon2fa. Hyphen is an illegal character for a Django project.

Comment: @trex, yes manually, see update in the answer. But don't copy files from poject(app) there, copy the folder with the project(app) itself. The folder created by `startproject` and all it's contents is your package, the one you want to install. So you need to put this package folder in another one, which is a folder containing all files regarding installation and distribution, e.g. `setup.py`, `README`, etc.

Comment: Nikita, it works! Thank you very much. Now my source code is inside `/home/trex/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon2fa`. Previously it didn't work because I placed setup.py and other packaging related files inside `django-horizon2fa/horizon2fa` folder. And now it works when I moved the files up to `django-horizon2fa`.

Comment: @trex, great! That's how it should be. :) I added a small note on package data to the answer, consider it in the future.